# C++ STL priority queue getting bad_alloc

Tags: c++, c++11, priority-queue, std

I'm trying to use a STL priority queue, defined as:

```
template <typename T>
using min_queue = std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, std::greater<T>>;
```

When running the following code:

```
Label kNN(int k, const Matrix &trainingSet, const std::vector<Label> &trainingLabels, Matrix &evSet, int i1, const DistanceF &f) {
    Timer timer("kNN Timer");
    min_queue<std::pair<double, Label>> distances;

    for (int i = 0; i < trainingSet.rows(); ++i) {
        distances.push(std::pair<double, Label>(f(trainingSet, i, evSet, i1), trainingLabels[i]));
    }

    int i = 0;
    int labels[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    while (!distances.empty() && i < k) {
        labels[(int)distances.top().second]++;
        distances.pop();
        ++i;
    }

    int maximum = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        if (labels[j] > maximum) {
            maximum = j;
        }
    }

    return (double)maximum;
}
```

I get the following error:

> malloc: *** error for object 0x230000000: pointer being freed was not allocated

Comment: Can you please provide minimal example that compiles and causes this error?

Comment: I can't, the code base is pretty long (unless you'd want to clone the repository!)

Comment: Look, bug can be anywhere in your code. There are little chance that it is in code snippet that you have provided. There are no manual memory allocation/deallocation in there, so this code should not cause double free error.

Comment: I don't use manual memory allocation at all, the code is written entirely using the stl, so it doesn't make much sense that there should be a double free. Also, the debugger points directly into the priority queue.

Comment: How about implementation of Matrix class for example? Can you provide full backtrace from gdb? Which pointer is fed to `malloc()` ?

Comment: According to the gdb, the error comes from the destructor of the priority queue. It tries to deallocate its internal vector representation, and it fails horribly at it. It looks like vector is trying to deallocate the std::pair in its destructor. I might have to create the std::pairs as new.

Comment: what is the `Label` type? It is just alias for `double` or have some logic for copying and/or moving?

Comment: It is an alias for double, indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being in a different part of the code: when copying a matrix, there was an error in the number of rows to copy, which caused the last rows of the source matrix no to be copied to the destination matrix. Hence, the vector did not initialize properly, and caused the bad alloc error.